# Is Maven injecting system property java.io.tmpdir into the JVM too late for JDK 17?

Tags: java, properties, maven-3, java-17

### The issue

I have a Maven project I'm trying to migrate it from JDK 11 to JDK 17.

In this project, I have a test using `@TempDir` from the library JUnit 5.
Internally, this library uses `java.nio.file.Files.createTempDirectory("junit")`.
This directory should reflect the value of the system property `java.io.tmpdir` if it is set.

`java.nio.file.Files.createTempDirectory("junit")` has parent directory set to `System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")` for JDK 11.

However, when I use Maven and JDK 17, `java.nio.file.Files.createTempDirectory("junit")` parent directory is `"/tmp"` instead of `System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")` :

```
mvn verify -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp/custom-tmpdir/ # will use /tmp anyway
```

If I use java directly (version 17), it works :

```
java -ea -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp/custom-tmpdir/ -javaagent:[redacted] -classpath [redacted] -junit5 groupId.artifctId.ClassTest,testMethod(java.nio.file.Path)
```

If I set the property using the environment variable `_JAVA_OPTIONS`, it works for Maven and JDK 17 too.

```
export _JAVA_OPTIONS='-Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp/custom-tmpdir/'
mvn verify
```

Using `MAVEN_OPTS` or `.mvn/jvm.config` doesn't work.

This lets me to believe that there's a problematic interaction between Maven and JDK 17, that causes Maven to inject the system property too late.

Am I missing something ? Should I use `_JAVA_OPTIONS` and call it a day ?

I'm using Maven 3.6.3, it's not the latest version, but I've read the release notes of next versions and I didn't find anything implying an upgrade might help me.

I'm using OpenJDK from Red Hat (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 21.9 (build 17.0.3+7-LTS, mixed mode, sharing).

### Sample application to demonstrate the behavior :

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demotmpdir</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-bom</artifactId>
                <version>5.8.2</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-launcher</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.10.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <java.io.tmpdir>${java.io.tmpdir}</java.io.tmpdir>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

src/main/java/org/example/Main.java

```
package org.example;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("createTempDirectory : " + Files.createTempDirectory("prefix").getParent());
        System.out.println("java.io.tmpdir : " + System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"));
    }
}
```

src/test/java/org/example/TempDirTest.java

```
package org.example;

import java.nio.file.Path;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.io.TempDir;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;

class TempDirTest {

    @Test
    void testTempDir(@TempDir Path tmpdir) {
        System.out.println("@TempDir : " + tmpdir.toAbsolutePath());
        System.out.println("java.io.tmpdir : " + System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"));

        final var actual = tmpdir.getParent().toAbsolutePath().toString();
        final var expected = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");

        Assertions.assertEquals(expected, actual);
    }
}
```

#### Sample output with JDK 11

Run the command :

```
mvn clean compile exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=org.example.Main verify -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp/custom
```

And get the following output :

```
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:3.1.0:java (default-cli) @ demotmpdir ---
createTempDirectory : /tmp/custom
java.io.tmpdir : /tmp/custom
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test (default-test) @ demotmpdir ---
[INFO]
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running org.example.TempDirTest
@TempDir : /tmp/custom/junit11934696726407367076
java.io.tmpdir : /tmp/custom
[INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.045 s - in org.example.TempDirTest
[INFO]
[INFO] Results:
[INFO]
[INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

#### Sample output with JDK 17

Run the command :

```
mvn clean compile exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=org.example.Main verify -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp/custom
```

And get the following output :

```
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:3.1.0:java (default-cli) @ demotmpdir ---
createTempDirectory : /tmp
java.io.tmpdir : /tmp/custom

[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test (default-test) @ demotmpdir ---
[INFO]
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running org.example.TempDirTest
@TempDir : /tmp/junit444674993039453082
java.io.tmpdir : /tmp/custom
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.061 s <<< FAILURE! - in org.example.TempDirTest
[ERROR] testTempDir{Path}  Time elapsed: 0.051 s  <<< FAILURE!
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: expected: </tmp/custom> but was: </tmp>
        at org.example.TempDirTest.testTempDir(TempDirTest.java:19)

[INFO]
[INFO] Results:
[INFO]
[ERROR] Failures:
[ERROR]   TempDirTest.testTempDir:19 expected: </tmp/custom> but was: </tmp>
[INFO]
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

Comment: I just checked with Maven 3.8.1 and it behaves the same as 3.6.3 in regards to this issue.

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov I've updated the post to make it clearer.

Comment: It would be helpful to know what `However, when I use Maven and JDK 17, it doesn't :` really means? Log output, failed test? Show the test case? Which maven-surefire-plugin version do you use? Also pom file would be help ful... Do you have an example project which shows the behaviour?

Comment: BTW: 3.8.1 of Maven os not even the latest https://maven.apache.org/docs/history.html

Comment: @khmarbaise I've changed the post to make what is the problem clearer. I thought it was clear enough from the inline comment in the code example.
Maven 3.8.1 is the latest available version in the repository of the company I'm working for. Requesting a newer version will take several days.
I'll make an example project later today.

Comment: @khmarbaise I added a sample application.

Comment: So the problem seemed to be related to the `@TempDir` annotation in the test.. in JDK11 it used the given property value while using JDK17 it is simply ignored... I've tested with the example project and get the same results..

Comment: @khmarbaise What gave you this impression ? Look at the output of exec-maven-plugin. The problem occurs there too !

Comment: After more investigation it looks like a bug in Maven/Surefire plugin (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SUREFIRE-2113) ...

Comment: Then there is the same problem with the maven-exec-plugin (goal java). If you look the output of the execution of the plugin, it changes between JDK11 and JDK17.

Comment: Just noting the line in this post `export _JAVA_OPTIONS=/tmp/custom-tmpdir/` should be `export _JAVA_OPTIONS='-Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp/custom-tmpdir/'`

Comment: @nickdos Indeed. Fixed

Answer (score 1):

All the time I was sure that if I need to pass system properties or environment variables to "unit tests" (actually maven-surefire or maven-failsafe) I need to specify that explicitly in plugin configuration, i.e.:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <systemPropertyVariables>
            <java.io.tmpdir>${java.io.tmpdir}</java.io.tmpdir>
        </systemPropertyVariables>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

or

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <systemPropertyVariables>
            <java.io.tmpdir>${java.io.tmpdir}</java.io.tmpdir>
        </systemPropertyVariables>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

the configurations above did work with both `.mvn/jvm.config` and `MAVEN_OPTS` until Java17. The reasoning behind such configuration is following:

- maven-surefire/failsafe forks dedicated JVM(s) to run tests unless `forkMode=none` (deprecated) or `forkCount=0` (I would say not recommended), and that dedicated JVM(s) know nothing about `MAVEN_OPTS` or `.mvn/jvm.config` (however exporting `_JAVA_OPTIONS` makes sense because it influences on all JVM processes)

So, I have no idea how/why it was working in your case without similar configuration.

In recent Java versions java team [had changed something](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/commit/6bb7e45e8e1a8f5a3b2f9c92b610fa4236f2eb90#diff-bce1cc542611fe2285622bbb95442ebc5ba4836fa8ef12438b2738a11cb375b7R60) in bootstrap process and now `java.io.tmpdir` system property initialises too early and surefires's "trick" with `System.setProperty()` does not affect `Files.createTempDirectory` anymore, so, the correct surefire/failsafe configuration for recent Java versions would be following:

```xml
<configuration>
    <argLine>-Djava.io.tmpdir=${java.io.tmpdir}</argLine>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I can assure you I didn't change the version of maven-surefire-plugin at any point. During my tests, I didn't even change `maven.compiler.source` or `maven.compiler.target` as the JDK  17 is supposed to be able to handle java 11.
Anyway, you bring an interesting point. I'll test that and try to see if the error is related to junit after all.

Comment: The `.mvn/jvm.config` is not related to maven-surefire-plugin/maven-failsafe-plugin it's only relevant to the command line client...

Comment: If you start your build from the command line you are correct (as I wrote) if you start from your IDE it's not relevant.. If something is not properly documented... open an issue to show what's missing or provide a pull request...

Comment: Unfortunately, the configuration of the maven-surefire-plugin isn't relevant. As you can see in my updated post, the problem occurs outside of the plugin execution. And the configuration didn't help.

Comment: Can you explain me: `as soon as someone from maven team starts keeping eye on jira and github` what you mean by that???

Comment: Thanks for the update @AndreyB.Panfilov, I'll test that tomorrow.

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov "we both know that maven team do not pay (much) attention to "external" CRs and PRs" external CRs / PRs? The apache maven project has trackers either in Github or JIRA https://maven.apache.org/plugins/ here you find the references. Furthermore telling that the Maven team is not paying much attention IS insulting the Maven team. All of them are volunteers and doing in their spare time. Do you expect enterprise support (SLA 24 hours) or alike?

Comment: A pretty simple PR to Maven what exactly is a pretty simple PR? And who is waiting for years?

Comment: @khmarbaise I may suggest you to discuss that somewhere else and remove your irrelevant comments.

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov Just for the record I'm one of the team.